# How to get current stream position using GoogleCast frameWork in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an application in which I will connect to the T.V using ChromeCast device, to achieve this I have used GoogleCast FrameWork in my project,

I am facing a problem when I try to access the approximate stream position of the video using the below statements,

GCKMediaControlChannel *mediaControlChannel = [[GCKMediaControlChannel alloc] init];
 NSLog(@"Approximate stream position is %f",mediaControlChannel.approximateStreamPosition);

But this is resulting in a time difference of 20 seconds.

I tried below statements to get the exact stream position,

GCKMediaStatus *deviceStatus = [[GCKMediaStatus alloc] initWithSessionID:sessionId mediaInformation:self.mediaInformation];

```
NSLog(@"Stream Position %f", self.deviceStatus.streamPosition);
```

As the above method is having two parameters,We need to send session as an integer, but we are getting session id as a string alpha numeric and upon converting this to integer resulting in 0.

Can any one help me to get the session ID as an integer, Or suggest me to get the current stream position with any different method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

approximateStreamPosition should give you a pretty accurate time, certainly not off by 20 seconds. You can take a look at our iOS [reference app](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following code to retrieve the stream position of the video that is currently being casted, and it's pretty accurate! The Google Cast SDK version that we use in our project is 3.5.3.

```
let position = Double(GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentSession!.remoteMediaClient!.mediaStatus!.streamPosition)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: but it's giving timings with a gap of 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can use approximateStreamPosition for the same.
Below code will print the more accurate time.

```
 if let position = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentSession?.remoteMediaClient?.approximateStreamPosition() {
                print("current time ",position)
 }
```